# Background task for push notifications on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I'm trying to register a background task on my Windows Phone 8.1 to receive and handle push notifications.At the moment everything is working when the app is opened (foreground+background), but a background task that is defined in the app.js does not work when app is closed.

This is defined in the package.phone.**appxmanifest**:

```
<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" StartPage="js/lib/backgroundTask.js">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="pushNotification" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
```

**backgroundTask.js**

```
(function () {
//var backgroundTask = Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIBackgroundTaskInstance.current,
//taskName = backgroundTask.task.name;

Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings.values["hello"] = "world";

close();
})();
```

this is what my **app.js** does:

```
  var taskName = "mySuperFancyBgTaskName";

  var registerBackgroundTask = function() {

    var btr = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration;
    var iter = btr.allTasks.first();
    var taskRegistered = false;

    while (iter.hasCurrent){
        var ta = iter.current.value;
        if (ta.name == taskName){
            taskRegistered = true;
            break;
        }
        iter.moveNext();
    }

    if (!taskRegistered){
        var builder = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        var trigger = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.PushNotificationTrigger();
        builder.setTrigger( trigger );
        builder.taskEntryPoint = "js\\lib\\backgroundTask.js";
        builder.name = taskName;

        try{
            var task = builder.register();
            //task.addEventListener("completed", onPushNotification);
        }
        catch (e){
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
}


var channel;
var pushNotificationManager = Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager;
var channelOperation = pushNotificationManager.createPushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

channelOperation.then(function (newChannel) {
    channel = newChannel;
    saveChannelUriInSettings(channel.uri);
    console.log("opened push notification channel with uri: " + channel.uri);
    registerBackgroundTask();
},
    function (error) {
        console.log("Channel could not be retreived. " + error.number)
    }
);
```

It seems that backgroundTask.js is never started,because there is nothing written in the localsettings. Tried to do some stuff there, but of course not able to debug there.

If I do

```
var onPushNotification = function (e) { ...}
channel.addEventListener("pushnotificationreceived", onPushNotification);
```

receiving raw push notifications works fine. So how do I get backgroundtask to work, so that it can save incoming push notifications? If it is working there is no need to define a event listener in the app to catch push notifications, right?

Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance!